# How to add a custom field to form in Umbraco

Tags: c#, forms, umbraco

I want to add a custom field to my form using Umbraco UI (not by code), I created a new type (label on my case)in Developer section, and when I'm on my form and choosing a field to edit my new custome label isn't on my options..

//mylabel - need to add to my form

[[image: I created mylabel]
//the options I get to add to my form - mylabel isn't one of them.. how can I get it ?

[image: mylabel doesn't shown as an option to add to my form]

Comment: It sounds look you are trying to build your own Form tool. Have you looked into Umbraco Forms (commercial) or Umbraco Formulate (open source)?

Comment: @Alex  no I haven't every example includs code and I am looking for an UI option to edit a control in Umbraco.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a new custom input type (field type) to use on an Umbraco Form.

Umbraco Forms does not use the normal Umbraco Data Types (as can be found in the developer section).

You can read up on how to do make a new field type [here](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Add-ons/UmbracoForms/Developer/Extending/Adding-a-Fieldtype).